# I want my document to look like this what can I do?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am trying to make my document look like this.

http://www2.hn.psu.edu/faculty/jmanis/kant/critique-pure-reason6x9.pdf

But I don't know enough LaTeX or typography :(

Comment: The font is `Garamond`; paper size seems to be `a6paper`.

Comment: Or close to 6in x 9in.  `pdfinfo` reports `Page size:      446 x 662 pts` which is about 6.2in x 9.2in, or about 157.3mm x 233.5mm.

Comment: What features of the document would you like to replicate other than the fonts and possibly the size?

Comment: Nothing else but the font in the document looks bold and crisp. I changed font of my document to Garamond but it doesn't look the same.

Comment: `pdffonts` report the font is `AGaramond`.  Does that look better for you?

Comment: I added some info regarding the font in my updated answer.

Comment: E-mail the professor who wrote the critique and ask for the template he used this may work depending on the person who wrote the critique.  If he is a nice guy, he should help you out.  If for some reason he doesn't want anyone to know how he set it up, he wont help at all.

Comment: @dustin `pdfinfo` reports original work has "Creator" `PageMaker 6.5` and "Producer" `Acrobat Distiller 5.0.5 (Windows)`.

Comment: That document was hard to read. It had not a single picture nor a plot in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some pointers to get you started:

- The font used is Garamond. [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) identified the font as Garamond Classico Regular; in [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/) you can find it: [`Garamond Classico`](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/garamond-classico/garamondclassico/) (not free).

  I used for the simple example below the package provided in [`Garamond fonts for LaTeX`](http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/).Of course, you could use another variant or XeLaTeX instead and a convenient version of the Garamond fonts (the one I linked to, for exmaple).
- The [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package was used to produce a similar paper size (6.19inx9.19in) with similar settings for margins.
- The [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package was used to produce the header and footers.

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=6.19in,
  paperheight=9.19in,
  centering,
  tmargin=1.2cm,
  bmargin=1.4cm,
  includehead,
  includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{garamond}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OR]{\itshape Immanuel Kant}
\fancyhead[EL]{\itshape The Critique of Pure Reason}
\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\Large\thepage}
\garamond

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-90]

\end{document}
```

Some pages from the output:

[image]

To customize the sectional unit headings you could use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

Comment: If you use the `scrbook` document class, you could setup your own pagestyles instead of using the `titlesec` package.

Comment: @klingt.net when I mentioned the `titlesec` package I was talking about the headings (possible label + number + title) for the sectional units (as in "Chapter 3 Title of the chapter") and not about footer/headers.

Comment: You meant headings not header, sorry my fault.